# Convergence of a sequence in trigonometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, soft-question, convergence-divergence

Is the sequence $(a_n)$ defined as  $$a_n :=\dfrac {\sin\Big( \dfrac {\pi}4+\dfrac n2 \Big)\sin\Big(\dfrac{n+1}2 \Big)}{\sin\Big(2n+2\Big)\sin\Big( \dfrac {\pi}4+\dfrac {n-1}2 \Big)\sin\Big(\dfrac{n}2 \Big)}\ , \quad\forall n\in \mathbb N $$

convergent ? If so then what is the limit ? What happens if $ \dfrac \pi 4$ is replaced by a rational number $q$ ? , or say a rational multiple of $\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not convergent. You may or may not know that if $a$ is any irrational number, then there is always an integer $k$ such that $ak$ is approximately an integer (and by choosing larger k, we can make this difference arbitrarily small). Since $2\pi$ is irrational, we know that there always exists an integer k such that $$2\pi k \approx  n  $$ for some integer n. If n is that value in the above equation, then 
$$\sin\frac{n}{2} \approx \sin{\pi k} \approx 0$$
Thus $\frac{1}{\sin \frac{n}{2}} $ is very large. Since in your expression, when $2\pi k \approx  n  $, the only term which is approximately zero is $\sin \frac{n}{2}$. (I'll let you check this yourself). When n is at these values close to $2\pi k$, the expression becomes very large. Since n becomes arbitrarily close to $2\pi k$, the expression is not only not convergent, it is unbounded!